# Mocha tests not failing when they should

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test my routes file, and mocha is returning success for all of my expects, even though I've coded a couple that should absolutely fail. I added a 2+2 = 5 test just to make sure *something* would fail. I have done() in my assertion blocks.

I'm using a MEAN stack, and I tried to test the node files with jasmine, since I'm already using that to test the Angular files, but got tons of crazy errors, so I threw all that out and decided to give mocha a try instead.

Results:

```
  Routes
    1) makes sure something fails
    GET /
      √ returns status code 200
    GET /nonexistent
      √ returns status code 400
    GET /api/todos
      √ returns status code 200
      √ returns a list of todos
```

Test file

```
// test/routes.spec.js

var request   = require('request');
var expect    = require('chai').expect;

describe('Routes', function() {

    var base_url = "http://localhost:8080/"

    // does fail as expected
    it("makes sure something fails", function () {
        expect(2 + 2).to.equal(5);
    });

    describe("GET /", function() {
        it("returns status code 200", function() {
            request(base_url, function(error, response, body) {
                expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                done();
            });
        });
    });

    //should fail
    describe("GET /nonexistent", function() {
        it("returns status code 400", function () {
            request(base_url + "/nonexistent", function (error, response, body) {
                expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                done();
            });
        });
    });

    describe("GET /api/todos", function() {
        it("returns status code 200", function() {
            request(base_url + "/api/todos", function(error, response, body) {
                expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                done();
            });
        });

        //should fail
        it("returns a list of todos", function() {
            request(base_url + "/api/todos", function(error, response, body) {
                console.log(body);
                expect(body).to.equal("abcd");
                done();
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Routes file:

```
// app/routes.js

var Todo = require('./models/todo');

module.exports = function(app) {

    // api ---------------------------------------------
    // get all todos
    app.get('/api/todos', function (req, res) {
        Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

    // create todo and send back all todos after creation
    app.post('/api/todos', function (req, res) {
        Todo.create({
            text: req.body.text,
            done: false
        }, function (err, todo) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(todos);
            });
        });
    });

    // delete a todo
    app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function (req, res) {
        Todo.remove({
            _id: req.params.todo_id
        }, function (err, todo) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(todos);
            })
        })
    })

    // application --------------------------------------
    app.get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use the `done` callback but none of your tests *declare* it in the parameters of the callbacks passed to `it`. Your first test, for instance, should be:

```
it("returns status code 200", function (done) { // <== Add parameter here!
    request(base_url, function(error, response, body) {
        expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        done();
    });
});
```

Without the parameter, Mocha considers the test to be synchronous. So it does not wait for `request` to call its callback, and ends right away. The fact that `done` is undefined does not lead to an error because the JavaScript interpreter does not get to `done()` before Mocha deems the tests over.

Comment: That fixed it. I knew it had to be something crazy simple!

Comment: Simple but very important addition that fixed my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a JavaScript novice and had to change my code from

```
it('getReports', () => {
  getReports()
    .then((res) => {
      assert.equal(200, res.statusCode);
    });
});
```

to

```
it('getReports', () => getReports()
  .then((res) => {
    assert.equal(200, res.statusCode);
  }));
```

i.e. Had to remove the first set of curly brackets.

After this the Mocha tests reported an error.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Node 8 you can use the native async/await approach for requests and testing.

First use request-promise or [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) instead request.

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');
```

Tests with async/await:

```
// testing success results - any error will fail the test
it('Returns status code 200', async () => {
    const response = await request(base_url);
    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
});

// testing for a particular error
it('Testing a particular error is thrown', async () => {
    let error;
    try {
        await request(base_url);
    } catch (err) {
        error = err;
    }
    expect(error).to.be.ok;
    expect(error.message).to.equal('Expected error message');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case running test files with the below command solved the problem.

```
node --unhandled-rejections=strict node_modules/.bin/mocha  --require @babel/register --require babel-polyfill test/**/*.test.js
```